# Where is the problem? Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js, express

**Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]**
I try to run the app on VS-code, and I get this message

```
/home/unkown/Node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as get] (/home/unkown/Node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202:15)
```

I update to latest version packages and restart ports, but still, show me this error. 
where is the hell? Please
My code

**Node/app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const index = require('./app_server/routes/index');

const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**Node/app_server/controllers/locations.js**

```
    /* GET 'home' page */
const homeList = (res, req)=>{
  res.render('index', {title: 'Home'})
};

/* GET 'Location info' page */
const locationInfo = (res, req)=>{
    res.render('index', {title: 'Location Info'})
  };

/* GET 'Add review' page */
const addReview = (res, req)=>{
    res.render('index', {title: 'Add Review'})
  };

  module.exports = {
    homeList,
    locationInfo,
    addReview
  };
```

**Node/app_server/router/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const ctrlLocations = require('../controllers/locations');
const ctrlOthers = require('../controllers/others');

/* Locations pages */
router.get('/', ctrlLocations.homelist);
router.get('/location', ctrlLocations.locationInfo);
router.get('/location/review/new', ctrlLocations.addReview);

/* Other pages */
router.get('/about', ctrlOthers.about);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: what is `users` in `app.use('/users', users);`

Comment: `const homeList = (res, req)` change this to `const homeList = (req, res)` same goes for all routes

Comment: Which exact line of your code does this error occur on?  You have to look back in the stack trace and see where it hits one of your files, probably `index.js`.  That would tell you which route definition is wrong.  Since you haven't shown the code for `ctrlOthers`, I would guess that `router.get('/about', ctrlOthers.about);` might be the culprit, but it could be other code that you haven't shown us too.

Comment: @jfriend00 I hide this code now, but still the same. Yes, I hide some resources but not necessary like views/ with .pug .

Comment: @Yousaf This is another file it's empty.

Comment: As I said already, you need to study the error stack trace of the error as see which line of YOUR file the error occurs on.  Then, we will all know which line needs fixing.

Comment: @kedarsedai I did but still same.

Answer (score 0):

`Router.get()` expects a function, but has gotten `undefined`. This much is clear from the error message.

In the absence of stack trace and deducing from the code you have pasted here, the problem seems to be at one of these places:

```js
/* Locations pages */
router.get('/', ctrlLocations.homelist);
router.get('/location', ctrlLocations.locationInfo);
router.get('/location/review/new', ctrlLocations.addReview);

/* Other pages */
router.get('/about', ctrlOthers.about);
```

Since the `ctrlLocations` module seems to be exported fine, the problem has to be in the `ctrlOthers.about` method. Either it's not defined or it's not exported properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ctrlOthers.about is the same file ctrlLocations. That way I didn't list it. Still same issues. Thank you bro.

Comment: `ctrlOthers` is not the same file as per the import statement. It is imported from `controllers/others` file whose code is not mentioned here. If that file is empty then it is the problem.